# Slim framework: Display an error page using Twig

Tags: error-handling, twig, slim

I would like to display a custom view (using twig view) on production when there's something going wrong with my slim3 application.

I read [the documentation concerning error handling](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html) but I cannot get the handler to display a twig view.

So this is working (displaying the error message in my browser):

```
if ('development' !== $container->get('settings')['environment']) {
    $container['errorHandler'] = function($c) {
        return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
            $c->get('logger')->critical("An error occured", [$exception->getMessage()]);

            return $response->write('An error occurred (message: "' . $exception->getMessage(). '").');
        };
    };
}
```

but this is not working, ie. it's not displaying the view using the template (instead I get a blank page in my browser):

```
if ('development' !== $container->get('settings')['environment']) {
    $container['errorHandler'] = function($c) {
        return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {

            $exceptionMessage = $exception->getMessage();
            $settings = $c->get('settings');
            $view = $c->get('view');
            $data = [
                'app' => $settings['app'],
                'title' => 'Error',
                'exceptionMessage' => $exceptionMessage
            ];

            $c->get('logger')->critical("An error occured", [$exception->getMessage()]);

            return $view->render($response, '500.twig', $data);
        };
    };
}
```

I really don't get why it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error handler cannot catch all errors. PHP Fatal errors and syntax errors it will not catch because of the way PHP deals with Fatal/Parsing errors. Unfortunately there is no way to deal with those types of errors in PHP. An example could be a syntax error or out of memory error. Neither is recoverable

Answer (score -1):

Just to add an observation,
to make twig render anything usually you **echo** $view->render ...